# Best Server to install Odoo

Tags: ubuntu, server, windows-server-2012, odoo-11

Which local server and OS should I choose if I want to host Odoo on it. Which will be more efficient and quick Linux or Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the number of users that will be using the application. You can go with any OS (Windows or Linux). The server configuration is what you should take care of.
You can see the details provided in the link https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/deploy.html#builtin-server in order to calculate the number of CPU workers and memory.

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much